# Can you launch an external exe and find a control and get its content?

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

Can you launch an external exe, one that you did not write and find a control on its form. Then get the contents of that control (just a string)?

I would like to launch a piece of software that has encrypted data in a HTML/RTF box, then strip the data out of the application.

Is this possible? If so what language?

Jeremy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to take the text out of the text box (Windows EDIT control) by sending it WM_GETTEXT message, but not from "generic" control. The only exception is when the control does let you do this by handling WM_GETTEXT message, but I suppose you don't think the developers of the application are *that* stupid to offer you such possibility? :)

So to answer your question - 99,9% chance that no.